# How will this code publish an image to a wall using Facebook Connect?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I would like to know what this code does exactly.

```
- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(FBDialog*)dialog { 
//[self doSomethingExciting];
FBStreamDialog *dialog2 = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease]; dialog.delegate = self;
dialog2.userMessagePrompt = @"Example prompt";
dialog2.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Facebook iPhone SDK\","
"\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\"," 
"\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\","
"\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\"," 
"\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\"," 
"\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],"
"\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}";
// replace this with a friend's UID
// dialog.targetId = @"999999"; 
[dialog2 show];
```

}

When I run it it asks me if I want to publish on my and my friends walls, but Im not sure how this will look on the walls. Also does it publish to the users walls and then show up in their friends incoming stream, like "most recent" or does it actually post on every friends wall?

Thanks

Comment: @Brad : Did u edit my question? The new question was not my question :P I agree my question wasnt so nicely stated, but I wanted to know which part did what. I know now.

Comment: he changed the title to make it clearer. "what will this code do" doesn't really help other people find the question if they have the same problem.

Comment: I know, but there is no answer for that question in these posts. :)

Comment: Sorry if the title is not what you intended.  I just wanted to clarify the question for those who later will be searching for something similar.  If there is a better phrasing for the question, please feel free to edit it yourself to reflect what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are posting an image to their stream.

Attachment is an escaped sequence of JSON that Facebook will pick up on and attach an image (and it looks like a link as well).

What the user will see is the image/link preconfigured as a wall post, and they will have a text box to enter their own text referred so as User Message Prompt.

Whether or not it shows up on friends streams depends on their settings, but ultimately, this is a news stream post, and thus has the potential to appear on their home page.

Comment: Is there a way to set the users text  that the field asks for? The dialog box prompts the user and the user than can enter text? I want to set that text for them.

Comment: My guess is no. I don't know, I've never needed to do that.

Comment: Thanks. SO if I want to set the description and caption to separate NSString values how would I do that? as the text is all in " " e.g. 

"\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\"

Comment: It's just a big string, so you would create it with NSString stringWithFormat@"", val1, val2  -- and so on

Comment: You can include a `message` as part of the JSON and that will get used as the default text. There's no way to disable the ability to edit the text, but including the message will pre-fill it. More docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish).

Answer (score 1):

An other answer already explained what the code does.

This is just a tip:
Create three fake FaceBook accounts, and connect them together.
Then use them to do your testings. So you will know exactly what happens, and do all the tests you need during development without loosing all your friends.